# Is text and ogg file thumbnailing available outside of Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, totem, thumbnails, pcmanfm

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and in Nautilus I can see thumbnails of several files including ogg (with embedded artwork) and text files, just like in this screenshot:

[image]

It's a nice feature.

I can't see ogg and text thumbnails in other file managers like PCManFM. Moreover, I have another machine with Arch linux and I even can't see them in Nautilus. I can see thumbnails for some other file types (eps, svg, png, jpg or pdf), but not for ogg and text files.

My question is, does ubuntu use a patched nautilus version with extended capabilities to see text and music thumbnailes? And, if so, is it possible to reproduce this extended capabilities to other file managers as pcmanfm?

Comment: Please don't mind, but I failed to see the question here. Do you want to know if Ubuntu uses a patched version or what?

Comment: @Anwar Yes, my question is if ubuntu's nautilus was patched to view text and music thumbnailers. Sorry, English is noy my language, I've edited my question to be more clear.

Comment: I don't have enough information to make an answer, but totem does the thumbnailing for nautilus.

Comment: @JorgeCastro Thanks Jorge, I've tested with Totem in Arch and now nautilus displays thumbnails of the ogg file. I have not any luck with the text files yet, maybe this is a only-ubuntu feature. And pcmanfm can't generate ogg thumbnails (nor ubuntu nor arch), it only read them if nautilus/totem create them.